# Problem Integrating Ninject v2 with Asp.net Webforms

Tags: c#, webforms, ninject

I am trying to integrate Ninject v2 with my asp.net webforms project. I am running .NET Framework 4.0.

My global.asax inherits from Ninject.Web.NinjectHttpApplication. I have also added the CreateKernel method:

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
  IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
  kernel.Bind<IUser>().To<User>();
  return kernel;
}
```

All my pages inherit from Ninject.Web.PageBase. I have also added the following httpmodule entry to my web.config:

```
<add name="NinjectHttpModule" type="Ninject.Web.NinjectHttpModule, Ninject.Web">
```

However when i run the application an InvalidOperationException is fired with the following:

"The type ASP.login_aspx requested an injection, but no kernel has been registered for the web application. Please ensure that your project defines a NinjectHttpApplication."

What am i doing wrong?

Kind Regards

Lee

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error in my ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms application.
I fixed that by using sole 'Global.asax' file with code, instead of 'Global.asax' + 'Global.asax.cs' code behind. E.g. you can use this standalone 'Global.asax' file:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="Ninject.Web.NinjectHttpApplication" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Ninject" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel() {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IUser>().To<User>();
        return kernel;
    }
</script>
```

Also I never added any httpmodules to web.config, and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new web application, the Global.asax.cs file is filled with empty methods:

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
    }
```

The [NinjectHttpApplication](https://ninject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/Framework/Web/NinjectHttpApplication.cs) also implements these methods, but the empty methods in the generated Global.asax.cs never call the methods on NinjectHttpApplication. To solve this, **remove the empty methods** or add a call to the base method:

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Application_Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

My case is a bit different - thought I'd share w/ you guys here - was testing it under IIS 7 then deployed it on Production Server which was IIS 6.

Got same error message '*.. but no kernel has been registered for the web application... Please ensure that your project defines a NinjectHttpApplication.*'

Tried all the above-mentioned solutions - none worked.
Found out that events in Global.asax.cs were somehow ignored.

To solve this, I got the file `PrecompiledApp.config` removed - may also need Recycling.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to register the HttpApplicationInitializationModule

```
<add name="HttpApplicationInitializationModule" type="Ninject.Web.Common.HttpApplicationInitializationModule, Ninject.Web.Common"/>
```

Comment: Ninject.Web.Common doesn't exist in version 2.2

Comment: @Lee, it does, it's a separate assembly.